# Seek permission prior to download

Tags: browser, download

I have users who use both IE and Firefox.  Some clients are in a domain; others are in a workgroup.  I have some questions:
a)  Is there a way I can set up IE, Firefox, and/or Chrome such that it will prompt the user for permission prior to downloading anything from the web?
b)  Also, is there a way I can set up IE, Firefox, and/or Chrome such that it will prompt the user before it executes anything when a link is clicked on the web?

Thanks, in advance, for all your help!

- Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Firefox, there is [PublicFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3911/) which would fit your situation perfectly.

Unfortunately, this behavior is impossible to implement in Chrome (at least on the client side) because of its extremely limited extension architecture.

Internet Explorer has a [kiosk mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780) although the problem here is that then you disable windowing, legit downloading, etc. as well. Unless you were to write something in-house, you'd have to stick to kiosk mode.

Comment: Yes, it worked beautifully!  I appreciate all your help, digitxp!